# Why am I receiving a replace function error when typing into a textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have two separate jquery popup, one of which is populated from a `GridView` data:

```
//THIS IS THE POPUP WHICH PRE POPULATES THE TEXTAREA VALUE FROM THE GRIDVIEW
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upPop" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div id="popupContactEM">
            <a id="popupContactCloseEM" title="Close Window">x</a>
            <div id="dvFourthEM" class="mainFirst">
                <div id="leftdiv1EM" class="leftdivspec"><sup style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">*</sup>Message:<br /><br /><b style="font-size: xx-small;">Character Count: </b><input maxlength="4" size="4" id="charCountE" style="border: none; font-size: xx-small; color: #E55302;" disabled="disabled" /><br /><b style="font-size: xx-small;">Word Count: </b><input maxlength="4" size="4" style="border: none; font-size: xx-small; color: #E55302;" id="wordCountE" disabled="disabled" /></div>
                <div id="rightdiv1EM" class="rightdivspec"><asp:TextBox ID="tbMessageEM" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="backgroundPopupEM"></div>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div id="popupContact">
    <a id="popupContactClose" title="Close Window">x</a>
    <div id="dvFourth" class="mainFirst">
        <div id="leftdiv1" class="leftdivspec"><sup style="color: #FF0000; font-weight: bold;">*</sup>Message:<br /><br /><b style="font-size: xx-small;">Character Count: </b><input maxlength="4" size="4" id="charCount" style="border: none; font-size: xx-small; color: #E55302;" disabled="disabled" /><br /><b style="font-size: xx-small;">Word Count: </b><input maxlength="4" size="4" style="border: none; font-size: xx-small; color: #E55302;" id="wordCount" disabled="disabled" /></div>
        <div id="rightdiv1" class="rightdivspec"><asp:TextBox ID="tbMessage" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

I am trying to display the WORD and CHARACTER count for either popup with and I have the following JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tbMessage").keyup(function () {
        WordCounter(this, 0);
    });

    $("body").on('keyup', "#tbMessageEM", function (e) {
        WordCounter(this, 1);
    });
});

function WordCounter(txt, whc) {

    if (whc == 0) {
        s = txt.value;
    }
    else {
        s = txt;
    }
    if (s.length == 0) {
        len = 0;
    }
    else {
        m1 = s.replace(/\s/g, '+');
        m = m1.replace(/^\s/g, '+');
        len = countWords(m);
    }
    if (whc == 0) {
        document.getElementById("charCount").value = s.length;
        document.getElementById("wordCount").value = len;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("charCountE").value = s.length;
        document.getElementById("wordCountE").value = len;
    }

}
function countWords(str) {

    str1 = str.replace(/\+*$/gi, "");
    str2 = str1.replace(/\++/g, ' ');
    var temp = new Array();
    temp = str2.split(' ');
    return temp.length;
}
```

When the popup which is not pre-populated opens, I am able to enter the text inside the `TextArea` and it gives me the count.

When the popup which is prepopulated opens, it does give the word/character count from the text inside the `TextArea` but when I go to enter or delete anything, I get the following error: `0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'replace'`:

[image]

Please help me resolve the error.

Comment: What does the debugger say? I'm curious to know what the value of `s` is as i'm assuming it's going to be null or not of the string datatype.

Comment: Because a DOM node does not have a replace method. `console.log(s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`txt` was coming up `[object HTML TextAreaElement]`.

I changed the code to this:

```
if (whc == 0) {
    s = txt.value;
}
else {
    s = $("#tbMessageEM").val();;
}
```

Instead of getting `txt`, I am getting the value of the textarea and it is working fine.

**Why it wasn't working**:

For the pre-populated textarea, I was loading the popup this way:

```
function loadPopupEM() {
    //loads popup only if it is disabled
    if (popupStatusEM == 0) {
        $("#backgroundPopupEM").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopupEM").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContactEM").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatusEM = 1;
        var w = $("#tbMessageEM").val(); //get the prepopulated text
        WordCounter(w, 1);
    }
}
```

When the popup loaded, I got the following error in the line `if (s.length == 0)`:

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
```

Comment: Why not always assign `s=txt.value`?

Comment: I updated my answer to show why it wasn't working :/

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty certain this is the culprit:

```
if (whc == 0) {
    s = txt.value;
}
else {
    s = txt;//This is a Node object
}
...
m1 = s.replace(/\s/g, '+');
```

You are sometimes trying to get `.replace` out of an HTML element object which does not exist.

Edit:
I'm not entirely sure what you hope to achieve here. The most obvious fix is to make sure that you are working with a string, so to avoid calling `.replace` on the node object, add another check to your `if` statement:

```
if (!s.replace || s.length == 0) {
```

Although, this might still be missing the underlying problem that `s` probably should be a string to begin with.

Comment: Any idea how I can fix it? Thanks.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge What is your expected behaviour? This is not clear why you are checking for `whc == 0` or not. Why not just using `s = txt.value;`???

Comment: I added `alert(txt)` inside the  function inside the `else` statement and it shows the text.

Comment: `whc` is checking to see which popup is being displayed at the moment.

Comment: How can I put one section inside `if (whc == 0)` { //one section } else { //two section}`?

Comment: I am curious as to why `.replace` isn't working because, `s = txt` is assigning `s` to the `txt` value, or am I wrong?

Comment: Can I share the page code to show you what is happening?

Comment: Use a jsfiddle as the actual webpage will likely change and we want to document what we are discussing for later visitors.

Comment: With the debugger on, I see the following error message when I enter something in the pre-populated textarea: `[object HTML TextAreaElement]`

Comment: Ok, I fixed it. I upvoted your answer because it paved the path for me to fix the error myself :). Thanks.